# Using eclipse to call database from Google Cloud SQL

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, web, mysql-workbench

I m trying to create a dynamic website where I can get data from the database and output it to the user.

I created the connection between MySQL workbench to Google cloud app engine, and I run on the cloud shell to test the database, it works.
But when I try to change the URL on eclipse, it just cannot connect to the server, and gives me errors "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()".

the URL sting are:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql:///film?cloudSqlInstance="
            + "causal-relic-333309:europe-west6:jiayaodb="
            + "&socketFactory = com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory"
            + "&user=root"
            + "&password=password";

private Connection openConnection(){
        // loading jdbc driver for mysql
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }

        // connecting to database
        try{
            // connection string for demos database, username demos, password demos
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
        } catch(SQLException se) { System.out.println(se); }
        return conn;       
    }
```

So I think is the connection error where I can't get it to connect to Google Cloud SQL.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy) to connect to the database from your local machine.